Template subclass of template class instantiated with value (not a type)
Cannot compile it in Visual Studio 2022 (different subversions).
template <int N>
struct A {
};

template <typename T0>
struct B {
    template <typename T1>
    using C = T1;
};

template <int N>
struct D {
    using E = A<N>;

    template <typename T2>
    using F = typename B<E>::C<T2>; // Error line
};

Generally, all compilers response with:
Error C2988 unrecognizable template declaration/definition
Error C2059 syntax error: '<'
Error C2238 unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Originally the problem occurred in a bit more complex structure, but I tried to extract it to that simpler snippet.
Putting the word typename does not help!
UPD. Added typename

Tl;DR of the dupe: using F = B<E>::C<T2>; needs to be using F = typename B<E>::C<T2>; to tell the compiler C is a type and not a data/function member

On a side note: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?

@NathanOliver I know what you mean. It DOES NOT work. Try to compile my example

Works here: https://godbolt.org/z/65MnY9P7h

reopened, noticed I used the wrong compiler.  The typename should work but it is not so probably a compiler bug.  FWIW link to the MSVC example: https://godbolt.org/z/rKW61Gdqo

@Symon In the GCC link D_bad does have the error because of the lack of typename but D_good doesn't because it has the typename.

@NathanOliver I don understand what you mean bcs there two errors in your link in 18 and 27 lines (https://godbolt.org/z/rKW61Gdqo MSVC 19)

Yes, MSVC gives the errors for both,  GCC OTOH only errors when the typename is missing as you can see here: https://godbolt.org/z/65MnY9P7h

Oh Got you! Yes GCC is cool today =)

In the line using F = typename B<E>::C<T2>;, C is a dependent template name.
To fix this problem, change the line to using F = typename B<E>::template C<T2>;. Compiler explorer
Clang diagnoses this for you:
<source>:16:30: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'C' as a dependent template name
   16 |     using F = typename B<E>::C<T2>; // Error line
      |                              ^
      |                              template 

Compiler explorer

Thanks for the answer! I was pretty convinced that I tried that too, but obviously I did not. Another thing convinced me that there is a compiler bug is that if you change in my example template using  to  the error has gone. Therefore, I suspect there are some compiler issues anyway.
